# Saving a ML pipeline as pickle in python

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-classification

Lets say that i have a ML pipeline for text classification. In this pipeline i'm using tfidf vectorizer and SVM from sklearn. After training the model, i need to save the vectorized class from tfidf and the svm model class as a pickle, right? Or i need save only the svm trained class?

I think the data to be classified must have the same pipeline that i used in the trained pipeline, is that right?